# Java divider is giving Zero value

Tags: java

I know this is very stupid question but need to ask,
I have values

```
int i = 12;
int j = 11;
float k = (i*j)/100;
```

result is giving 0.0 but here i want more that 2 digits decimal points , How can i achieve it,
I am getting wrong data, it is showing 0 which is wrong

Comment: I would expect the result to be `1.0`, because that would be the result of `(12*11)/100` with integer division in Java.

Comment: `1.0` has a decimal point, though?

Comment: @kevinsa5: the result is stored as a float.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy yes, so the variable would hold `1.0`, but "the result of `(12*11)/100` with integer division" is not `1.0`. It's nitpicky, I know.

Comment: @kevinsa5: true, it basically would be `float k = 1;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because all the calculation on the **right hand side are of in integer**, that is why the result `0`.

At least one of the operand should be a floating point number like:

```
float k= (i * j) / 100.0;
```

Comment: `12*11/10` should give 1 as result not 0. What's going wrong?

Comment: That's correct. Or they can use `100f` as well, I believe.

Comment: @Teeg, in C# they can use `100f`, I am not sure about java :)

Comment: @Habib Yup, it works as well in Java. I just did a quick test.

Comment: @Christian, it should return `1.0`, I guess the OP is not showing the right values in the question.

Answer (score 1):

In primary school I learnt integer division.  We used to calculate things like 13 divides by 5 is 2 remainder 3.  The maths you learnt at school still applies in the computing world. 11 * 12 is 132 and 132 / 100 is 1 and 132 % 100 is 32 (the remainder)

I wouldn't use `float` as `double` has half a billion times the accuracy.

```
double k = (i * j) / 100.0;
```